# Сортировка массива типа ([ ['a', 4], ['c', 6], ['x', 8]) по алфавиту и числу

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

```
let text = "As long as I'm learning something, I figure I'm OK - it's a decent day."

const letterFrequency = (text) => {
   let uniq = Array.from(new Set([...text.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '')]));
   return uniq
      .map(el => [el, text.match(new RegExp(el, 'gi')).length])
      .sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
};
```

**Должен вернуть**

```
[["i", 7], ["a", 5], ["e", 5], ["n", 5], ["g", 4], ["s", 4], ["m", 3], ["o", 3], ["t", 3], ["d", 2], ["l", 2], ["r", 2], ["c", 1], ["f", 1], ["h", 1], ["k", 1], ["u", 1], ["y", 1]]
```

Как мне можно реализовать такую сортировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если числа равны, то сортировать по алфавиту, если нет, то по числу.

```js
let text = "As long as I'm learning something, I figure I'm OK - it's a decent day."

const letterFrequency = (text) => {
  let uniq = Array.from(new Set([...text.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '')]));
  return uniq
    .map(el => [el, text.match(new RegExp(el, 'gi')).length])
    .sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[1] == b[1]) {
        return a[0].charCodeAt(0) - b[0].charCodeAt(0);
      }
      return b[1] - a[1];
    });
};

console.log(letterFrequency(text));
```

Answer (score 1):

<s>Более быстрый вариант, за счет сокращения числа проходов:</s>
Другой вариант (по факту, он оказался медленнее ):

```js
const letterFrequency = text => {
  const unsorted = [...text.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, '')]
    .reduce((r, c) => ((r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1), r), {}); 
  return Object.entries(unsorted)
    .sort((a, b) => (b[1] - a[1]) * 10 + a[0].localeCompare(b[0])); 
}

let text = "As long as I'm learning something, I figure I'm OK - it's a decent day.";  
console.log(JSON.stringify(letterFrequency(text)));
```

Хитрость этой реализации сортировки в распределении результатов вычитания на десятичные разряды: в старшем находится разность частот, а в младшем - "разность" символов.
Таким образом можно сортировать и более чем по двум полям... пока хватает диапазона значений `number`.

p.s.: Если нужна поддержка кириллицы, `/\W/g` надо заменить на `/[^\wа-яё]/gi`.

Comment: Но сейчас прогнал jsperf - он показывает что начальный вариант быстрее на 33%. Видимо, оптимизации V8 :) Оставлю ответ как альтернативный вариант решения.